# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x000e7fc) in xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I got an app that takes a video and then shows the preview.

The part of the code which takes the video and sends to the preview is the following:

```
 if(!self.camera.isRecording) {
        self.segmentedControl.hidden = YES;
        self.flashButton.hidden = YES;
        self.switchButton.hidden = YES;

        self.snapButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
        self.snapButton.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

        // start recording
        NSURL *outputURL = [[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]
                             URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test1"] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"mov"];
        [self.camera startRecordingWithOutputUrl:outputURL];
    }
    else {
        self.segmentedControl.hidden = NO;
        self.flashButton.hidden = NO;
        self.switchButton.hidden = NO;

        self.snapButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        self.snapButton.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

        [self.camera stopRecording:^(LLSimpleCamera *camera, NSURL *outputFileUrl, NSError *error) {
            VideoViewController *vc = [[VideoViewController alloc] initWithVideoUrl:outputFileUrl];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        }];
    }
```

Then, the video is sent to an activity called VideoViewController:

```
 @import AVFoundation;

 @interface VideoViewController ()
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *videoUrl;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer *avPlayer;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *cancelButton;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *sendButton;
 @end

 @implementation VideoViewController

 -(instancetype)initWithVideoUrl:(NSURL *)url {
     self = [super init];
     if(self) {
         _videoUrl = url;
     }

     return self;
 }

-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

// the video player
self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:self.videoUrl];
self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

self.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
//self.avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[self.avPlayer currentItem]];

CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

self.avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.avPlayerLayer];
```

According to xcode, the error is in the `self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:self.videoUrl];` part. When I build the project appears that `self VideoViewController *   0x146b91d0`

How could I do in order to resolve that error?

Comment: You need to provide the complete crash log or stacktrace..

Comment: Do you see any messages in the debug console?

Comment: It's doesn't appear any message

Comment: What makes you think `initWithVideoUrl` is called?  If it wasn't then that URL would be `nil` which might be the issue.